# i am getting an error in visual studio code terminal that the mongod server does not connect to the database

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

when i run my website i am getting this error:-

```
(node:12724) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongooseServerSelectionError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND loaclhost        
    at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (d:\html program\websites\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:846:32)
    at d:\html program\websites\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:351:10
    at d:\html program\websites\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:32:5
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at promiseOrCallback (d:\html program\websites\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:31:10)    
    at Mongoose._promiseOrCallback (d:\html program\websites\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:1149:10)
    at Mongoose.connect (d:\html program\websites\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:350:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (d:\html program\websites\app.js:7:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1068:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1097:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:933:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:774:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:12724) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:12724) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: There can be very many reasons for such an error, so please share more about your setup. Also please format the code properly, it is very hard to read it unformatted.

Comment: Somewhere in your code there is a typo, misspelled word `localhost` as `loaclhost`. Once you fix the typo, this problem should go away.

Comment: @PawelVeselov thankyou so much sir. The error is solved ,i was puzzled since yesterday. i tried everything and the error was this typo mistake. thankyou again